# Replicate the functionality of Java's "Pattern.quote" in a JavaScript RegExp

Tags: java, javascript, regex, string, firefox-addon

In Java, you might try to make a regular expression that would match the URL `stackoverflow.com` using `Pattern.compile("stackoverflow.com")`. But this would be wrong because the `.` has special meaning in regular expressions. The easiest way to fix this is to write `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("stackoverflow.com"))` which comes out to: `Pattern.compile("\\Qstackoverflow.com\\E")` which ["quotes" the entire string](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

I want to do the same thing in JavaScript, but JavaScript's regular expressions don't assign any meaning to `\Q` and `\E` and it doesn't look like there is a JavaScript equivalent, so I'm not sure how to go about it. My first thought (see my answer below) is to just put a backslash before any character that has a special meaning in a JavaScript regex, but this seems potentially error-prone and I suspect that someone might know of a better way.

This is for a Firefox extension so Mozilla-specific solutions are okay.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this in the future and is curious, I ended up solving it a different way. I wanted a regex that matched `"` followed by a particular string, followed by `"`. I ended up just searching for something like `/"[^"]+"/` (quote, a bunch of non-quote characters, then another quote) and then going through all the matches to find the one that matched the particular string I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on my suggestion, it would look something like this:

```
// A RegExp that matches all the characters which have a special meaning in a RegExp
var regexpSpecialChars = /([\[\]\^\$\|\(\)\\\+\*\?\{\}\=\!])/gi;
```

I'm not sure if this is quite right, since some characters (like `!` and `=`) only seem to have special meaning in certain situations. But assuming that it is, then you would do

```
var quotedURL = url.replace(regexpSpecialChars, '\\$1');
```

to replace, for instance, all `$`'s with `\$`'s. Then you can just build the RegExp from `quotedURL`:

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp(quotedURL, 'gi');
```

Comment: AFAIK, escaping everything but letter and digits works, too. It makes the result even less readable, but it's a bit simpler (and IIRC there was somewhere a statement that it will work even when additional chars get their special meaning, but I don't know anymore what language it was about:D).