# Sanitize string of regex characters before RegExp build?

Tags: javascript, regex, sanitization

I want to use a string to perform a global regex, but it might have regex characters in it. What's the best way to escape all regex characters in a string before building a regex with it?

Basically I might have something like this;

```
var test = 'test.';
var regex = new RegExp(test, 'ig');
```

I need 'test.' to become 'test\.' so it doesn't behave in unexpected ways.

Comment: Similar to a question I asked a few months ago! I never really got an answer though so maybe you will... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614440/replicate-the-functionality-of-javas-pattern-quote-in-a-javascript-regexp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
new RegExp(test.replace(/[#-.]|[[-^]|[?|{}]/g, '\\$&'));
```

This escapes the following:

- The characters between `#` and `.`, so: `#$%&'()*+,-.`
- The four characters `[`, `\`, `]`, and `^`
- These characters `?`, `|`, `{`, `}`

...by prepending a backslash before each occurrence (as `$&` [Inserts the matched substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement), and the `g` flag means to replace all instances.)

---

Alternatively, if you're looking for a shorter version, try:

```
new RegExp(test.replace(/[#-}]/g, '\\$&'));
```

This will end up escaping a lot more than it should, but it won't harm anything.

Comment: you forgot the /g global flag, to replace all the occurrences (I tried to edit your post, but it tells me that the change must be at least 6 characters)

Comment: I had some issues with the second one (the regex would not match some things it should for some reason), but the first one works great!

Comment: Apparently, the short form doesn't work on Qt 5.15, so it might be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all special RegExp characters with their escaped version:

```
test = test.replace(/[\\\.\+\*\?\^\$\[\]\(\)\{\}\/\'\#\:\!\=\|]/ig, "\\$&");
```

Comment: But some of those characters are only special in certain contexts, aren't they? Does that cause a problem at all?

Comment: In other contexts escaping the character won't harm the RegExp match string, it will just end up being unnecessary.

Comment: no need to escape `#`, `/`, `'` or `:`.  You also need `-` and `,`, and you don't need to escape most of those characters in the context you're in.  It can simply become `/[-\\.,_*+?^$[\](){}!=|]/`

Comment: Also no need for case insensitive `/ig` in answer just `/g`. @MarkKahn why comma and underscore?

Comment: `,` is for repetition ranges: `{1,3}`.  Not sure why I added an underscore, it was 6 years ago :D  Seems unnecessary

Comment: btw, this is answered very similarly in the MDN docs, about mid-way down the page, as of today, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-unicode-escape-es6