# Sanitizing string for grepl

Tags: regex, r, escaping

Please consider the following

```
vector <- c("C++", "Abba", "Beatles", "C++")
string <- vector[1]

grepl(string,vector)

# Error in grepl(string, vector) : 
#  invalid regular expression 'C++', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
```

I need a function to sanitize my vector before passing it to regex.

I tried to write adapt a regex function from [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300183/sanitize-string-of-regex-characters-before-regexp-build) but without success.

```
regexSanitized <- function(string) {
  return(gsub("/[#-}]/g", "\\$&", string))
}
```

Comment: Use: `grepl(string, vector, fixed = TRUE)` or possibly `vector %in% string` and forgo regex all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured I'd throw this down as an answer:

Use: `grepl(string, vector, fixed = TRUE)` or possibly `vector %in% string` and forgo regex all together.