# Java's Pattern/quote equivalent in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When I am in Clojure, I can use `(re-pattern (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote foo))` to exactly match the pattern string with another string. How can I do a similar thing in ClojureScript?

Edit: I also found this - [Replicate the functionality of Java's "Pattern.quote" in a JavaScript RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614440/replicate-the-functionality-of-javas-pattern-quote-in-a-javascript-regexp)

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in Clojure or Javascript function for this.

This clojure function should escape special regexp characters in a string:

```
(defn re-quote [s]
  (let [special (set ".?*+^$[]\\(){}|")
        escfn #(if (special %) (str \\ %) %)]
    (apply str (map escfn s))))
```

http://ideone.com/QXbbB

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this extensively so you may want to get a second opinion before using this code to sanitize potentially evil strings.*

Comment: Actually `Pattern/quote` encloses expression with `\Q` and `\E`.

Answer (score -1):

I should say first off that I use neither ClojureScript nor Javascript, but a quick search for ClojureScript regex support brought me to this page: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure, where under the "**Other Functions**" section, it says: "ClojureScript regular expression support is that of JavaScript", providing this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp. That next link seems to provide you with what you would be looking for (as a person who doesn't use JavaScript, I am cautious to say for certain).

**Edit**
Ooh, and maybe the answer to this old question here: [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression) will give you a more complete answer.